# Custom font in Android app and ActionBar

Tags: java, android, fonts

I've been busting my head all afternoon on implementing a custom font in my Android app. First, I had troubles with a custom font in my navigation drawer. That doesn't seem to work. So I decided to try the Actionbar title, but I'm having equal problems.

I found this website http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2013/03/styling-the-android-action-bar-with-a-custom-font/ and decided to try it.

I created a custom java file with the code below:

```
package vimen.vimenlogin;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.MetricAffectingSpan;
import android.util.LruCache;

public class TypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {
    /** An <code>LruCache</code> for previously loaded typefaces. */
    private static LruCache<String, Typeface> sTypefaceCache =
    new LruCache<String, Typeface>(12);

    private Typeface mTypeface;

    /**
     * Load the {@link Typeface} and apply to a {@link}.
     */
    public TypefaceSpan(Context context, String typefaceName) {
        mTypeface = sTypefaceCache.get(typefaceName);

        if (mTypeface == null) {
            mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext()
                .getAssets(), String.format("fonts/%s", typefaceName));

            // Cache the loaded Typeface
            sTypefaceCache.put(typefaceName, mTypeface);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
        p.setTypeface(mTypeface);

        // Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
        p.setFlags(p.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.setTypeface(mTypeface);

        // Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
        tp.setFlags(tp.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
}
```

Afther that, I put the method in my `main.java` file:

```
public void restoreActionBar()
{
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("testing");
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    // Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
    actionBar.setTitle(s);
    //actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}
```

However, I'm getting this error `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made` coupled with a crashing app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TypefaceSpan` does not take a font path. It only works with the built-in font families. It is impossible to tell from the code snippets as they stand whether you are using your `TypefaceSpan` or the built-in `TypefaceSpan`.

(pro tip: use a different class name for yours than `TypefaceSpan`)

The error message in general means either Android cannot find the font file or cannot interpret it for some reason. Given your code, your font file would need to be:

```
assets/fonts/fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf
```

in your project, as you have `fonts/` both in your `TypefaceSpan` and in your use of that `TypefaceSpan`. If the font file is not there, either move it or fix up your code to reference its actual location.

Comment: But that's what the custom class is for

Comment: Thanks, the problem was indeed the double use of `/fonts/`. Do you know if I can use this method for the navigation drawer as well?

Comment: @user3740505: A navigation drawer is just a `ListView`. You are in charge of how you render your rows in your `ListView`, including what font to use.